# Azure ARM Scale Set - deploy and update solution

Tags: azure, deployment, virtual-machine, updates, azure-vm-scale-set

I have been browsing web regarding Azure Scale Set service and I have been able to find a lot of resources connected to scaling and deploying of scale set, however I was not able to find any information regarding deployment and update of the solutions deployed to the machines within scale set. Please what is the best practise when I want to host e.g. a web solution within scale set? How should I perform deployment and updates?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on how you configure the scale set to be a web solution to begin with...

For example, if you create the VMSS with a template and then configured the VMSS with a custom script extension, then you could run the template deployment again and update the script.

If you used DSC (windows vm) then you could just update the artifacts source and DSC will do the update while the VMs are running.

Comment: Strange, but first one (with custom script extension) does not work for me. On first provisioning of VM my script is executed, but on subsequent deployments through ARM - my script is not executed

Comment: In my case, solution was to set upgradePolicy  to Automatic for VMSS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PowerShell for deployment to the Scale Set.

```
$customConfig = @{
 "fileUris" = @("https://$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/script.ps1");
 "commandToExecute" = "PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted .\script.ps1";
};

$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMScaleSetName $vmssname

Add-AzureRmVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -Publisher Microsoft.Compute -Type CustomScriptExtension -TypeHandlerVersion 2.0 -Name "runscript" -Setting $customConfig

# Send the new config to Azure
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name "$vmssname" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```